# I wish there is a

Tags: word-usage

- I wish there is an option of buying something for 3rd time.
- I wish there is an option for buying something.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What exactly should we correct?

Comment: Option of buying or option for buying

Comment: **I wish there was an option to buy something**

Comment: "I wish there _were_ an option to buy something." - [subjunctive mood.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subjunctive_mood) Though you will frequently hear SovereignSun's version, and someone will be along shortly to claim that that is more idiomatic.

Comment: The 1st would it not be correct

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know whether there is an option to buy it, but you want there to be:

- I hope there is an option to buy it.
- I hope there will be an option to buy it.
- I want there to be an option to buy it.
- I want to be able to buy it.
- I want to have the option of buying it.

If you know there isn't such an option, but you wish that there were:

- I wish there were an option to buy it.
- (*less formally*) I wish there was an option to buy it.